# Is selenium dependency required even for android version >4.2?

Tags: android, selenium, appium

For Android 4.2 and above, selenium dependency is not required. However, I am unable to find DesiredCapabilities class without that.
Have I misunderstood something? Or Selenium dependency is still required? I've added that java client jar.
I have followed http://appium.io/
Any explaination / document / link would be helpful.

Comment: A line from Appium.io  _Appium drives various native automation frameworks and provides an API based on Selenium's WebDriver JSON wire protocol._. Java client you mentioned is a jar with APIs is required to communicate to your device via appium. Hence Selenium dependency is must regardless of android version.

Comment: Still if it is not clear, please mention the line from above site, which may have brought you to this question.

Comment: @mk08 I think this confused me http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#running-your-test-app-with-appium-(android)

Comment: Oh you mean this section: `Running your test app with Appium (Android devices < 4.2, and hybrid tests)`.?

Comment: [let's continue this in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96947/room-for-mk08-and-androidlearner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood that yes , the dependency is required.
What confused me to post such a question was this link :http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#running-your-test-app-with-appium-%28android%29 
Quoting Mitaleek's comment : Appium drives various native automation frameworks and provides an API based on Selenium's WebDriver JSON wire protocol..
I am posting this as answer so that if anyone else has similar doubt,it may be cleared.